# How to combine PIVOT and aggregation?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is my sample schema and data (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d8b7/3/0):

```
CREATE TABLE cpv
(
  ClientId INT, 
  CodeName VARCHAR(20), 
  Value VARCHAR(30),
  LastModified DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO cpv (ClientId,CodeName,Value,LastModified)
VALUES
(1000, 'PropA', 'A', '2014-05-15 17:02:00'),
(1000, 'PropB', 'B', '2014-05-15 17:01:00'),
(1000, 'PropC', 'C', '2014-05-15 17:01:00'),
(2000, 'PropA', 'D', '2014-05-15 17:02:00'),
(2000, 'PropB', 'E', '2014-05-15 17:05:00');
```

I need to reshape it into:

```
ClientId PropA PropB PropC LastModified
1000     A     B     C     '2014-05-15 17:02:00'
2000     D     E     NULL  '2014-05-15 17:05:00'
```

There are Two operations involved here:

- aggregation of the LastModified - taking the Max within the same ClientId
- pivoting the CodeName column

I have no idea how to combine them.

[This SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d8b7/3/0) demonstrates pivoting the CodeName column:

```
SELECT PropA,PropB,PropC
FROM (
  SELECT CodeName,Value FROM cpv
) src
PIVOT (
  MAX(Value)
  FOR CodeName IN (PropA,PropB,PropC)
) p
```

But it does not group by ClientId and neither takes the Maximum of the LastModified.

[This SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d8b7/10) demonstrates grouping by the ClientId and aggregating LastModified:

```
SELECT ClientId,MAX(LastModified) LastModified
FROM cpv
GROUP BY ClientId
```

But it totally ignores the Name and Value columns.

How can I group by ClientId, aggregate by taking the Maximum LastModified within the group and also pivot the CodeName column, again within each group?

**EDIT**

The answer is available [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d8b7/11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(SELECT ClientID,PropA,PropB,PropC
 FROM (
 SELECT ClientID, CodeName,Value FROM cpv
 ) src
 PIVOT (
 MAX(Value)
 FOR CodeName IN (PropA,PropB,PropC)
 ) p)

SELECT DISTINCT cte.ClientID, PropA, PropB, PropC, MAX(LastModified) OVER(PARTITION BY cte.clientid ORDER BY cte.clientid) MaxLastModified FROM cte
INNER JOIN cpv ON cte.clientid = cpv.clientid
```

Demo [here](http://rextester.com/CVM50175).

Comment: Thanks, that does it. Only I have slightly modified your solution to use group by instead of distinct, which comes out a bit simpler.

Comment: Fair enough. I wasn't really able to revisit my answer due to work, but if it provided a base, that's good too